# Modal com id=undefined

Tags: php, modal, crud

Pessoal estou com problemas com um código.

O fragmento abaixo chama o modal:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-client="<?php echo $cliente['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

O código do modal é esse aqui:

```
<!-- MODAL DELETE -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Excluir Orçamento</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Deseja realmente excluir este orçamento?</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Sim</a>
                <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Não</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O JS que faz a ponte é esse aqui:

```js
// PASSA UM ID PARA O MODAL E ATUALIZA O LINK PARA EXCLUSÃO
$('#delete-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var id = button.data('service');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Registro: ' + id);
    modal.find('#confirm').attr('href', 'delete.php?id=' + id);
})
```

Quando clico no botão para excluir, o modal abre mas o valor que está sendo atribuído a variável ID (código de exclusão) está igual a undefined.

A URL fica assim: gfinan/clientes/delete.php?id=undefined

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Em nenhum lugar do botão existe o atributo `data-service`, de onde vc está querendo atribuir à variável `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja este trecho do código:

```
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
var id = button.data('service');
```

A primeira linha você pega o botão que abriu a modal. Na segunda você está tentando pegar o valor do atributo `data-service` do botão, mas esse atributo não existe, veja:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-client="<?php echo $cliente['id']; ?>">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</a>
```

Existe sim um atributo `data-client`, mas creio que não seja esse valor que queira pegar(?).

O que você deve fazer é inserir no botão o atributo `data-service` e colocar nele o código que deseja, algo como:

```
<a data-service="<?php echo $CÓDIGO DO ID; ?>" href="#"...
```

Onde tem `$CÓDIGO DO ID;` você coloca o código que puxa o id do que você quer deletar.

---

Se for o valor em `data-client` que é o que você deseja enviar, aí basta trocar a segunda linha do trecho citado no início da resposta por:

```
var id = button.data('client');
```

Comment: resolvido. alterei para var id = button.data('client');